# MariaDB Out-of-Order Parallel Replication and OPTIMIZE TABLE

Tags: replication, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I am using MariaDB 10.4 and have question about Out-of-Order parallel replication.

I am optimizing databases(about 400GB of data) on Master every week. As optimizing DB on master do not have any negative impact, then replicated OPTIMIZE commands on slaves results in huge replication lags (up to half an hour). Can i use Out-of-Order parallel replication (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/parallel-replication/#out-of-order-parallel-replication) and set different gtid_domain_id for the OPTIMIZE commands on master to fix this ?

Please note that tables on master are being updated all the time. I am unsure if this is safe approach or not ?

Maybe it will be safer to NOT replicate OPTIMIZE commands on master and run them independly on all slaves ? Will this affect replication / lag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Anti-OPTIMIZE**

If you are using InnoDB (which you should be using), then `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is almost totally useless.  Stop running that.

If you are `DELETEing` huge chunks of a table, and that led you to want to `OPTIMIZE`, then let's discuss alternatives.

**Replication issues**

It is possible to avoid replicating any command(s):

```
 SET SESSION binlog = OFF;   -- I forget the details
 OPTIMIZE TABLE ...;
 SET ...   -- restore replication
```

But it seems like you would want to `OPTIMIZE` on the Slaves, where you are doing `SELECTs`?

If you have a graceful way to take a Slave out of rotation, you could do a "rolling" `OPTIMIZE` across the slaves, one at a time.

**ANALYZE**

If the goal is to refresh the "statistics", then `ANALYZE TABLE` is much faster, hence less intrusive.

**PARTITION**

If "old" data is being purged, then Partitioning is much faster than `DELETE`, and has no need for `OPTIMIZE`; should we discuss that?

Comment: Yes, all tables are InnoDB. Many tables have thousands of rows removed / added each hour. Sometimes it grows by few milions rows per day, and sometimes it shrinks by few million rows. Also OPTIMIZE TABLE for innodb is doing recreate + ANALYZE which sometimes also help optimizer to take better decisions. Many of these tables have 450M+ rows and dozens of queries per second and it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will do optimize tables on master with disabled binlog and independently optimize tables on slaves on different days as slaves are behind proxysql which automatically drop ones with replication lag so this will solve the problem.